# Spring boot with CalendarIntervalTrigger program

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to integrate spring boot with CalendarIntervalTrigger. I am able to find programs based on Simple Jobs and Cron Jobs but not based on Calendar based. Can anyone provide me some insights?

https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-quartz-scheduler-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample usage

```
TriggerBuilder<CalendarIntervalTrigger> tb = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withSchedule(
                CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder
                        .calendarIntervalSchedule().withInterval(
                                interval, unit))
        .forJob(jobName, jobGroup);
```